# Calculate line integral over half circle?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am stuck with solving line integral.

$
\int_l \frac{y^2dx-x^2dy}{x^2+y^2}
$

Over half circle $\quad x=a cos(t)\quad y=bsin(t),\quad t\epsilon[0,\pi]
$

I am able to get integral with substition of x, y, dx and dy but then I am stuck with the given integral.

$
x = acos(t);\quad dx=-asin(t)dt \\
y = bsin(t);\quad dy=bcos(t)dt\\
$

$
\int_0^\pi \frac{-a^2sin^2t*asint + b^2cos^2t*bcost}{a^2cos^2t+b^2sin^2t}dt
$

$
\int_0^\pi \frac{-a^3sin^3t + b^3cos^3t}{a^2cos^2t+b^2sin^2t}dt
$

I am currently stuck with this integral. Any shortcuts how to solve it, or there is no easy way?

Comment: If you're integrating over a half-circle, why are you parametrizing an ellipse?

Comment: @kobe Well text of problem goes likes this: Calculate [given line integral] over half circle x=acost, y=bsint from t1=0 to t2=pi. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's strange because unless $a = b$, the parametrization is for an ellipse, not a circle.

Comment: @kobe I double checked now. You are right. Well 2 hours of struggling because I have misread It. Thanks a lot!